# How can I update the values of certain columns, ignoring the others, while also inserting a row if necessary?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with a composite primary key on the columns `FirstName`, `LastName`. I want to set the `Age` column while leaving `Address` alone. If a row doesn't exist for the person, create it (and leave `Address` as NULL).

I tried REPLACE INTO like this:

```
REPLACE INTO
    answers
    (
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Age
    )
VALUES
    (
        :first_name,
        :last_name,
        :age
    )
```

But this also has the effect of nulling out `Address`.

I found something to do with `ON DUPLICATE`, but that seems to be mysql only, then I heard `ON CONFLICT` can do something similar so I started reading [this page](https://database.guide/how-on-conflict-works-in-sqlite/) and got very confused. I also can't find any examples on using `ON CONFLICT` with a composite primary key.

I'm using SQLite 3.31.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
INSERT INTO answers (FirstName, LastName, Age, Address)
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :age, :address)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
SET Age = EXCLUDED.Age;
```

Or, if you don't want to set a value for `Address` in the inserted row:

```
INSERT INTO answers (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :age)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE
SET Age = EXCLUDED.Age;
```

If the combination of `:first_name` and `:last_name` already exists in the table then the `UPDATE` statement will be executed which will not affect the column `Address`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tPgsBpPZ).

Comment: So you don't have to pass any parameter to `CONFLICT` at all?

Comment: @JackM if there are more than 1 unique constraints defined in the table and you want to apply the UPSERT logic only to a specific constraint violation then you would have to specify this with `CONFLICT(FirstName, LastName)`: https://dbfiddle.uk/NV5DsBW1 If, like your case, there is only 1 unique constraint or you want the logic applied to any unique constraint violation then you can omit the column names.